# Format a equation to only show 2dp

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT `Product Name`, `Price`, `Modification`, `Description`, `Image`, (`Price` * (1 - (`DiscPercent` / 100))) AS `Discount`
FROM `products` 
WHERE `Producer_ID` = '1' 
AND `DiscPercent` > 0
```

If I run this query, it shows DiscPercent as 999.9000. Is there any way I can get it to only have 2dp

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `round()` function Please change like this:

```
 SELECT `Product Name`, `Price`, `Modification`, 
`Description`, `Image`, round((`Price` * (1 - (`DiscPercent` / 100))),2)
 AS `Discount`
    FROM `products` 
    WHERE `Producer_ID` = '1' 
    AND `DiscPercent` > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast to a decimal:

```
cast(`Price` * (1 - (`DiscPercent` / 100)) as decimal(5, 2))
```

You can also convert to a string using `format()`, but you might as well keep the value as a number.